# The character returned is not the same as stored.

Tags: java, char, stack

When I use the infix as 73+2*, the characters are not stored in their current form. it prints other values. It should be printing the first operand as 7, but something else is printed.

```
public char postfixOperation(String infix) {
    operatorStack.reset();
    int firstOperand=0;
    int secondOperand=0;
    for(int j=0;j<infix.length();j++){    // loop until the end of the line for a string (expression)
        // Check for numbers 
        if( infix.charAt(j) =='0' || infix.charAt(j) =='1' || infix.charAt(j) =='2'|| infix.charAt(j) 
        =='3'|| infix.charAt(j) =='4'|| infix.charAt(j) =='5'|| infix.charAt(j) =='6'|| infix.charAt(j) 
        =='7'|| infix.charAt(j) =='8'|| infix.charAt(j) =='9' ){
            operatorStack.push(infix.charAt(j));
                        }
        //check for '+'
        else if( infix.charAt(j)=='+'){
            firstOperand = operatorStack.pop(); // pop first operand
            System.out.println(firstOperand);
            secondOperand = (int) operatorStack.pop(); // pop second operand
            operatorStack.push((char) (firstOperand + secondOperand));
        }
        //check for '-'


       else if( infix.charAt(j)=='-'){
            firstOperand = (int) operatorStack.pop();   // pop first operand
            secondOperand = (int) operatorStack.pop(); // pop second operand
            operatorStack.push((char) (firstOperand - secondOperand));
        }
        //check for '*'
        else if( infix.charAt(j)=='*'){
            firstOperand = (int) operatorStack.pop();   // pop first operand
            secondOperand = (int) operatorStack.pop(); // pop second operand
            operatorStack.push((char) (firstOperand * secondOperand));
        }
        //check for '/'
        else if( infix.charAt(j)=='/'){
            firstOperand = (int) operatorStack.pop();   // pop first operand
            secondOperand = (int) operatorStack.pop(); // pop second operand
            operatorStack.push((char) (firstOperand / secondOperand));
        }

    }        
    return operatorStack.pop();
}
```

Comment: It seems as if you're asking us to debug your code for you.

Comment: `but something else is printed` - and what might that something else be?

Comment: I think you need to change your operator stack to contain strings, and not remove a number from your equation until you've determine you've passed the entire number.  Also, you're loading `char`s into your stack, and pulling them out as `int`s; I'm pretty sure `(int)'1'` equals 49 in Java.

Comment: I have a string of 77*2-, how can i break into integers and work on it?

Comment: I created an example of parsing the equation at http://pastebin.com/YZjWkVU6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep using `char` variables and performing operations on their numeric values. This means, for example, that `'9' - '7' == 2`, not `'2'`. Instead, subtract `'0'` from your input characters and use the numeric values instead.

Comment: ok, so what can be done? i am new to java